# Problemas ao ordenar uma array

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma array de objetos:

```
$arrayTeste[] = array(
    "horario" =>$arr[$i]['horario'],
    "valor" =>$valorSoma,
    "nome" =>$arr[$i]['nome']
);
```

O horário estava todo desordenado, então mandei ordenar usando a função sort().

```
sort($arrayTeste);
```

Eis o resultado:

```
10:00:00 - 11:00:00 | 2

11:00:00 - 12:00:00 | 7

12:00:00 - 13:00:00 | 0

13:00:00 - 14:00:00 | 0

14:00:00 - 15:00:00 | 4

15:00:00 - 16:00:00 | 0

16:00:00 - 17:00:00 | 0

17:00:00 - 18:00:00 | 0

18:00:00 - 19:00:00 | 0

19:00:00 - 20:00:00 | 0

20:00:00 - 21:00:00 | 0

8:00:00 - 9:00:00 | 0

9:00:00 - 10:00:00 | 0
```

ele ordenou, mas o problema são os horários **8:00:00 - 9:00:00** e **9:00:00 - 10:00:00**, provavelmente é porque não há o número 0 na frente deles, por exemplo: **0**9:00:00; **0**8:00:00.
seria este o motivo? pra ordenar especificamente o horário, devo fazer diferentemente do que fiz no sort()?

Comment: Notei que você tem feito algumas perguntas ultimamente @chocolatemontana, porém não se registrou no Stack Overflow. Acho importante você se registrar e participar mais ativamente da comunidade. Faça um [tour] e veja qual a proposta da comunidade e não se esqueça de marcar as respostas que solucionam sua questão como resposta aceita.

Comment: O problema é que você está ordenando strings e não números... Acredito que o mais ideal para este caso seja a função [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php) ou então converter todos os horários para um timestamp (utilizando o mesmo dia para todos) para que a ordenação possa ser feita utilizando-se números inteiros.

Answer (score 2):

Ao invés de `sort()`, use o [`natsort()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.natsort.php). Da documentação:

> Essa função é um implementação do algoritmo que ordena strings alfanuméricas da forma como um ser humano faria mantendo associação de chave/valor. Isso é chamado de "ordenação natural". Um exemplo da diferença entre esse algoritmo e o algoritmo com o qual o computador classifica strings (usado em sort()).

Exemplo:

```
<?php

$datas = array(
'10:00:00 - 11:00:00',
'11:00:00 - 12:00:00',
'12:00:00 - 13:00:00',
'13:00:00 - 14:00:00',
'8:00:00 - 9:00:00',
'9:00:00 - 10:00:00',
);

var_dump($datas);

natsort($datas);

var_dump($datas);
```

Saída:
Antes (primeiro vardump)

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "10:00:00 - 11:00:00"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "11:00:00 - 12:00:00"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "12:00:00 - 13:00:00"
  [3]=>
  string(19) "13:00:00 - 14:00:00"
  [4]=>
  string(17) "8:00:00 - 9:00:00"
  [5]=>
  string(18) "9:00:00 - 10:00:00"
}
```

Depois (segundo vardump)

```
array(6) {
  [4]=>
  string(17) "8:00:00 - 9:00:00"
  [5]=>
  string(18) "9:00:00 - 10:00:00"
  [0]=>
  string(19) "10:00:00 - 11:00:00"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "11:00:00 - 12:00:00"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "12:00:00 - 13:00:00"
  [3]=>
  string(19) "13:00:00 - 14:00:00"
}
```

Comment: não deu certo, como se faz? natsort($arrayTeste); ? natsort($arrayTeste['horario']) ?

Comment: @chocolatemontana veja exemplo: http://3v4l.org/SaLJQ